# connecting to database in java problems

Tags: java

I have a table Employee in my oracle database and I connected it with java. When I add info in it works but when I try to get info it gives old information(which I deleted already)  too . I am sure I connected the right database and closed connection. I think ResultSet stores the data. Is it possible? Thanks

```
    public static Connection getConnection(){

    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
     }

    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.err.println (e) ;
                System.exit (-1) ;
    }

    try {
           connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
           "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl",
           "mamur",
           "mamur"
         );
    }

    catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
        System.err.println (e) ;
        System.exit (-1) ;
    }

    return connection;    
}
```

---

```
         public String [] getStudents(String query) throws SQLException{

    ConnectionClass con = new ConnectionClass();
    connection = con.getConnection();       

            statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);   

            while(rs.next()){
                list.add(rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2));
            }                       

            rs.close();

    String [] arr = new String [list.size()];

    list.toArray(arr);      
    return arr;
}
```

and I set the result Jlist

Comment: Share your code that you tried yet.

Comment: Looks like you forgot the commit before reading.

Comment: I commit but steel wrong

Comment: Value of query String?

Comment: Have you connected to the database with a GUI app and checked that the data is there?  Have you successfully run your query SQL in there and seen results?

Comment: Also, you say you are committing and closing the connection but neither of those things are in your code.  It would be good if you could edit your question to show them.

Comment: You didn't commit your changes after the creation of the new data. this is why your code is returning the old ones.